# How to create a loop which creates single mosaic images for each day (from a selected time period) from an ImageCollection using Python?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

[image]I have been trying to create mosaic images from the region of japan from the MCD19A2.006 imagecollection (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_006_MCD19A2_GRANULES#description).

I wish to create a single mosaic image for each day of the year from the period 2013/03/01 to 2020/03/01 and be able to download it locally to my computer. I am able to create an image for one day but I am unsure how to create a loop to do this for each day and have it named differently using python. I would also like to know how I can mosaic all the bands together as currently I am only able to do this with one band at a time.

Below is test code that I did for one day (2020/01/01) using only the Optical_Depth_047 band.

```
roi= ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[122.791488, 29.85464], 
      [122.791488, 45.462539], 
      [146.780501, 45.462539],
      [146.780501, 29.85464]]], None, False)

collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES') \
    .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02') \
    .filterBounds(roi) \
    .select('Optical_Depth_047')

mosaic = collection.mosaic()

Map.addLayer(mosaic, {'min': 0, 'max': 500, 'palette': ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']}, 'mosaic')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I have understood your question correctly. You want to merge all the images that have the same date into one image. So you combine all the satellite tiles together for a given date. The below code should help you.

```py
'''
mergeByDate is a function that merges images together that have the same date.

@ imgCol: [ee.ImageCollection] mandatory value that specifies the image collection to merge by dates with.

Returns ee.ImageCollection
'''
def mergeByDate(imgCol):
    #Convert the image collection to a list.
    imgList = imgCol.toList(imgCol.size())
    
    # Driver function for mapping the unique dates
    def uniqueDriver(image):
        return ee.Image(image).date().format("YYYY-MM-dd")
    
    uniqueDates = imgList.map(uniqueDriver).distinct()

    # Driver function for mapping the moasiacs
    def mosaicDriver(date):
        date = ee.Date(date)
        
        image = (imgCol
               .filterDate(date, date.advance(1, "day"))
               .mosaic())
        
        return image.set(
                        "system:time_start", date.millis(), 
                        "system:id", date.format("YYYY-MM-dd"))
    
    mosaicImgList = uniqueDates.map(mosaicDriver)
    
    return ee.ImageCollection(mosaicImgList)
```

---

Then you call the function on your image collection where you store the satellite images. Like so:

```py
collection = mergeByDate(collection)
```

This does it for all bands that the images contain. No need to loop. The map function can map a function over a collection.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to combine this with batch exporting using code from https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools, and it worked out well!